# Get lowest maximum value across various ranges in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, spreadsheet, data-analysis

I'm doing some recreational data analysis and after spending a the day learning how to use VLOOKUP() I've hit a wall I don't think I can figure out through just googling. I have a dataset of a bunch of ideas, linked to the people I want to do them with, a bunch of names associated with them, and the subjects of the ideas. I've been doing fun stuff like how many ideas each subject has, how much of a person's ideas are about a given subject, and how much of a subject's ideas are with a given person. I've also been working out some stats for the whole sheet: total ideas, average ideas per person, average ideas per subject, who has the largest "subject monopoly", whatever seems interesting.

I want to have a stat for who has the most diverse range of subjects, which I would want to indicate by checking who has the lowest highest "subject focus" (how much of a person's ideas are a given subject). I know how I would do this with javascript or python: I want to run through all the "subject focus" values, dividing them up by person, and discarding all but the highest per-person. Then I compare each of these "maximum subject focuses", and pick out the lowest, and display the name associated.

Despite how clear it is in my head, I have no idea how to actually start doing that in Google Sheets. Any advice? Has anyone had to perform a similar operation?

Edit: So the closest I've gotten is to make a new column populated with the formula `=if(MAX(FILTER(G:G, A:A=A3)) = 0, "", MAX(FILTER(G:G, A:A=A3)))`, where G:G is where I have the "subject focus" of a given person, and A:A is the name of the person (it starts at A3 because rows 1 and 2 are header). Then, to display the stat, I just have `=CONCATENATE("Most diverse idea list: ", VLOOKUP(MIN(J3:J), {J3:J,A3:A}, 2, FALSE), " (", TEXT(ROUND(MIN(J3:J) * 100, 2), "#.00"), "% max focus)")`, where J:J is the new column I added. It works, but obviously this is incredibly messy and if there's a way to do this without making a whole new column for data storage that would be much preferred.

Edit 2: [Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17rH5fhyEFoSl1G4PpeWmRMPV_i4bGEd0v25Qva-WwQk/edit?usp=sharing) a general mockup of the sheet I'm using, since I'd rather not share it directly.

Comment: Hi, Please share a sample of your data and desired results. I generally get the idea but I am not sure about some details

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I don't want to share the sheet itself for various reasons, but I whipped up this copy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17rH5fhyEFoSl1G4PpeWmRMPV_i4bGEd0v25Qva-WwQk/edit?usp=sharing. The actual dataset is a bit more complicated, but not in any ways that should affect this specific problem.

Comment: Formula in column G: `=if(E19 = "","", E19/(COUNTIFS(A:A, A19) - COUNTIFS(A:A, A19, C:C, "")))`

Why in its denominator is `-COUNTIFS(A:A, A19, C:C, "")`? 
Isn't E always 0 in this case?

Indeed in column E: `=if(iserror(FIND(",", C19)), if(C19 = "","", COUNTIFS(C:C, C19, A:A, A19)), "")`. 
If so then the formula in column G can be simplified.

Comment: In the original sheet there are some ideas that aren't linked to subjects, as column C is also automatically populated using a formula that pulls from a bunch of potential subjects. That formula just displays "" if there are no matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `query()` to get the max value in `G` grouped by the names in column `A`, and wrap it in another `query()` to get just the first result. Put this formula in cell `N1`:

```
=query( 
  query( 
    A1:H, 
    "select A, max(G) 
     where A is not null 
     and G is not null 
     group by A", 
    1 
  ), 
  "order by Col2 asc 
   limit 1", 
  1 
)
```

...and this formula in cell `I16`:

```
="Most diverse idea list: " & N2 & " (" & text(O2, "#.00%") & " max focus)"
```

To see how this works, try putting this formula in cell `K1`:

```
=query( 
  A1:H, 
  "select A, max(G) 
   where A is not null 
   and G is not null 
   group by A", 
  1 
)
```

If you need to place these results in column `J` for each name, put this formula in cell `J3`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      A3:A, 
      K2:L, 
      columns(K2:L), 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

This is an array formula that fills whole column in one go, so you will have to clear column `J3:J` before inserting the formula to make room for the results.

To put the first two formulas together so that no helper columns are needed, use this:

```
="Most diverse idea list: " & 
join( " (", 
  query( 
    query( 
      A2:H, 
      "select A, max(G) 
       where A is not null 
       and G is not null 
       group by A 
       label max(G) '' 
       format max(G) '0.00%' ", 
      0 
    ), 
    "order by Col2 asc 
     limit 1", 
    0 
  ) 
) & " max focus)"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really cool (and definitely more advanced than I've reached so far)! One thing I don't quite understand is how to then isolate this to just one cell. Can I somehow use this within and array and apply my VLOOKUP code (Currently `=CONCATENATE("Most diverse idea list: ", VLOOKUP(MIN(J3:J), {J3:J,A3:A}, 2, FALSE), " (", TEXT(ROUND(MIN(J3:J) * 100, 2), "#.00"), "% max focus)")`) to that?

Comment: Edited the answer to include a formula for cell `I16`.

Comment: Thank you, I was moreso asking if this entire formula can be isolated to one cell, such that you don't need to make any new columns?

Comment: You can _hide_ the helper columns if they get in the way. Nevertheless, edited the answer to show how to combine the first two formulas so that no helper columns are needed.